# Insert an element into a sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote this function to **insert** an element into a **sorted array** such that array would still be sorted after adding the element.

But something is wrong. I know that my code has a lot of edge cases and probably I'm over complicating the algorithm but I really want to fix it.

> My Code :

```
private static <E> void insert(E e, E[] arr, int count, Comparator<E> comp) {
    if (count == 0) arr[0] = e;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (comp.compare(arr[i], e) >= 0) {
            // we found an element that is >= to e
            // we want to add new element at index i, currently arr[i] is occupied
            // by larger element, so we need to adjust
            if (i != 0) {
                i--;
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        } else if (i + 1 == count) {
            // this is the last iteration of the loop so we want to add element at i + 1
            i++;
        } else {
            // keep looping to find an element
            continue;
        }

        // we need to move elements to the right to make space
        for (int j = count; j > i; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
        }

        arr[i] = e;
        break;
    }
}
```

[My repo](https://github.com/amir734jj/insert-into-sorted-array/tree/f887928e4bc6d0b8fa5d359e43a59305be104671)

Comment: Look at any implementation of `insertion sort`. It performs exactly the same action.

Comment: I understand. Most implementation look through the array from right to left to find a place to add. But I wanted to loop from left to right instead.

Comment: Hint: `Arrays.binarySearch`. @Node.JS **no implementations loop in any direction!!** (except very naive and arguably incorrect ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code, I should have not decremented `i`

```
private <E> void insert(E e, E[] arr, int count, Comparator<E> comp) {
    if (count == 0) {
        arr[0] = e;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (comp.compare(arr[i], e) >= 0) {
            // we found an element that is >= to e
            // we want to add new element at index i, currently arr[i] is occupied
            // by larger element, so we need to adjust
        } else if (i + 1 == count) {
            // this is the last iteration of the loop so we want to add element at i + 1
            i++;
        } else {
            // keep looping to find an element
            continue;
        }

        // we need to move elements to the right to make space
        for (int j = count; j > i; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
        }

        arr[i] = e;
        break;
    }
}
```